# Using reactjs render inside a function

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to reactjs, so I thought using the react.render inside a function would allow me to create multiple different components. But it always shows the last component I created with the function. I guess it overwrites the previous components.

```
function renderComment (commentInfo, src, username, commentText, replyText){
    React.render(<Comment commentInfo={commentInfo} src={src} username={username} commentText={commentText} replyText={replyText} />, document.getElementById('comments'));
}
```

How can I prevent this? I would like to add a component each time and not overwrite it.

Comment: What does "I would like to add a component each time and not overwrite it" mean? Are you saying that you want to append to the page each time a button is clicked or some type of event takes place? You'll find more help if you give more detailed explanation.

Comment: Sorry and yes each time the function renderComment is called, by  a button click or through another function, it should append a component to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be done this way. Instead, create a top-level component and render it onto a page. Store your comments as collection of objects in your top-level component's state, and render them in 'render' method:

```
React.render(<CommentsList />, document.getElementById('comments'));

//...

var CommentsList = react.createClass({
    onAddComment: function() {
        var comments = this.state.comments.slice();
        var newComment = /* create your new comment here somehow */;
        comments.push(newComment);
        this.setState({
            comments: comments
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var comments = this.state.comments.map(function(comment) {
                            return <Comment commentInfo={comment.commentInfo} src={comment.src} username={comment.username} commentText={comment.commentText} replyText={comment.replyText} />
                        }, this);

        return (
            <div>
                {comments}
                <input type="button" value="Add comment" onClick={this.onAddComment} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```